# What is the proper way to close PhotoEditorSDK ReactUI?

Tags: javascript, photoeditorsdk

According to their documentation, there is an event for when the photoeditorsdk get close.

> the editor will emit a `close` event when the user clicks the close button.

[Source](https://docs.photoeditorsdk.com/guides/html5/v3_6/introduction/configuration)

However, there is no indication on how to properly close the editor. I tried to remove any items inside of div editor like this:

```
    // Closing
    imageEditor.editor.on('close', (result) => {
        console.log('Closing.....');
        // TODO: This is not working.
        $("#" + imageEditor.editorId).empty();
    });
```

The problem with this solution is that if I tried to load the editor again does not work.

What is the proper way to close PhotoEditorSDK ReactUI?

Comment: Not a proper solution, But have did the same by using jquery for ex. `$('.pesdk-react-topBar__button--withIcon')[0].click() ` . This jquery code close the current screen and open the initial screen. like when you click on the new image button. Note: I am using V4

Answer (score 1):

You should do the following:

```
imageEditor
    .editor // @link https://docs.photoeditorsdk.com/apidocs/html5/v4/PhotoEditorSDK.html
    .on('close', () => imageEditor.editor.dispose());
```